# Is it possible to deep traverse React Children without rendering?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Is there any way to grab all of the `bar` properties in `<Wrapper/>` below 'statically', e.g. without rendering?

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

class Foo extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return(
      <div>
        <span bar="1" /> // want to collect this 'bar'
        <span bar="2" /> // want to collect this 'bar'
      </div>;
    );
  }
}


class FooTuple extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return(
      <div>
        <Foo />
        <Foo />
      </div>;
    );
  }
}

class Wrapper extends React.Component {
  render() {

    React.Children.forEach(this.props.children, child => {
      console.log(child.props); // can only see <FooTuple/> not <Foo/>
    });

    return(
      <div>
        {this.props.children}
      </div>;
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Wrapper>
    <FooTuple />
  </Wrapper>, 
document.getElementById('app'));
```

Here's a webpackbin with a naive attempt that tries to iterate over `child.children` which obviously doesn't work, but it's here if it's helpful:
http://www.webpackbin.com/EySeQ-ihg

Comment: you can get to the level of the current render, not deeper. when you run your log, you are in the Wrapper.render(), so you can see only the stuff defined by whatever rendered that, which is the stuff in the last ReactDOM.render call, `<FooTuple>`. from `FooTuple.render()`, you could see `<Foo/>`, and from `Foo.render`, your `<span>`s.

Comment: It's difficult to answer this question without knowing what the context or use case is. As noted they won't be accessible where you have the `console.log()` right now, but you're rendering it into the DOM, so the `<span>s` will be in the DOM.

Comment: @JMM the use case is I'm building a Form that needs `name` properties (and one or two other properties) for arbitrarily deeply nested component children of the Form. I need to be able to grab them at first run/instantiation time for things like validation etc. I was thinking it should be possible to traverse the children of the form and decorate them, maybe using React.cloneElement, but I wasn't able to traverse deeper than the first-level children.

Comment: @Muers It's still not clear to me what you're trying to do or how the two things you mentioned relate to each other. You can pass props down arbitrarily deep, you can pass `ReactClass`es or `ReactElement`s or callback functions as props, and if you *really* want to you could use context.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**TL;DR;** Nope that's not possible.

--

I've once encountered the same problem trying to traverse a tree of deeply nested children. Here are my scoop outs:

### Required knowledge

- `children` are what's placed inside the `jsx` open and close tags, or injected directly in the children prop. other than that `children` prop would be `undefined`.

  ```
  <div className="wrapper">
    // Children
    <img src="url" />
  </div>

  /* OR */

  <div classname="wrapper" children={<img src="url" />}>
  ```
- `children` are an opaque **tree-like** data structure that represents the react elements' tree, it's likely the output of `React.createElement` that the `jsx` implements when transpiling.

  ```
  {
    $$typeof: Symbol(react.element),
    type: 'div',
    key: null,
    ref: null,
    props: {
      className: "wrapper",
      children: {
        $$typeof: Symbol(react.element),
        type: 'img',
        key: null,
        ref: null,
        props: { src: 'url' },
      }
    }
  }
  ```
- Creating `React` elements doesn't mean that they are instantiated, think of them like a descriptor that `React` uses to render those elements. in other words, instances are taken care off by `React` itself behind the scenes.

### Traversing children

Let's take your example and try to traverse the whole tree.

```
<Wrapper>
  <FooTuple />
</Wrapper>
```

The opaque children object of these elements would be something like this:

```
{
  $$typeof: Symbol(react.element),
  type: Wrapper,
  key: null,
  ref: null,
  props: {
    children: {
      $$typeof: Symbol(react.element),
      type: FooTuple,
      key: null,
      ref: null,
      props: {},
    }
  }
}
```

As you can see `FooTuple` props are empty for the reason you should know by now. The only way to reach it's child elements is to instantiate the element using it's `type` to be able to call it's render method to grab it's underlying child elements, something like this:

```
class Wrapper extends React.Component {
  render() {
    React.Children.forEach(this.props.children, child => {
      const nestedChildren = new child.type(child.props).render();

      console.log(nestedChildren); // `FooTuple` children
    });

    return(
      <div>
        {this.props.children}
      </div>;
    );
  }
}
```

This is obviously not something to consider at all.

### Conclusion

There is no clean way to augment deeply nested children or grab something from them (like your case). Refactor your code to do that in a different manner. Maybe provide a setter function in the `context` to set the data you need from any deep child.

Comment: Thanks Mohammed for showing me the way of [`Context`](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html). If you are trying to recursively process a whole sub-tree for whatever reason, as I was, then it's very likely a sign that `Context` is what you really need.